# Oracle SQL condition only when

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to figure out how to define that conndition depends only on specific value from the column

```
WHERE ( ( CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE=TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID))  {?} (CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME='Type of workload' )  AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE='Performed' )
```

Condition `( CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE=TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID))` should be applied only when `CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME` is `(CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME='Type of workload' )`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question:

```
WHERE   (CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE = TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID)
         AND CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME = 'Type of workload'
         AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE = 'Performed')
         OR 
         ( (CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME  IS NULL OR CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME <> 'Type of workload')
         AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE = 'Performed')
```

That can be rewritten:

```
WHERE   CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE = 'Performed' 
        AND ( (CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE = TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID)
             AND CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME = 'Type of workload'
            )
             OR 
             ( (CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME  IS NULL OR CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME <> 'Type of workload') )
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank you for your suggestion. Your rewritten query is very close to what I need but at the end I don't have correct result.

Comment: I can provide you with a full query and what is my final goal.

Comment: Try to explain it in a clear way and with sample data (post CREATE TABLE and INSERT with sample data) and desired result please

Answer (score 0):

I would use the UNION operator with 2 distinct queries

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME='Type of workload' AND CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE=TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID) AND AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE='Performed'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME<>'Type of workload' AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE='Performed'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is entire query and goal is to have a list of all available fields for specific issue when Type of workload is Performed and Resolution Accepted (RESOLUTION=8).

The Problem is the condition which has to be used only for CUSTOMVALUE='Performed' for CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME = 'Type of workload'

Condition:

```
AND  ( CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE=TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID) AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE='Performed' )
```

Entire query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
  JIRAISSUE.ISSUENUM,
  JIRAISSUE.SUMMARY,
  PROJECT.PNAME,
  CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME,
  CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE,
  CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.ID,
  CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.NUMBERVALUE,
  CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE,
  ISSUETYPE.PNAME
FROM
  JIRAISSUE,
  PROJECT,
  CUSTOMFIELDVALUE,
  CUSTOMFIELD,
  CUSTOMFIELDOPTION,
  ISSUETYPE
WHERE  ( CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.ISSUE=JIRAISSUE.ID )
  AND  ( CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.CUSTOMFIELD=CUSTOMFIELD.ID )
  AND  ( CUSTOMFIELD.ID=CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMFIELD)
  AND  ( CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMFIELD=CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.CUSTOMFIELD ) 
  AND  ( JIRAISSUE.ISSUETYPE=ISSUETYPE.ID  )
  AND  ( PROJECT.ID=JIRAISSUE.PROJECT  )
  AND    CUSTOMFIELD.CFNAME  IN  ( 'Type of workload', 'ANA-PROG extramuros','ANA-PROG intramuros','TEC-CONS extramuros','TEC-CONS intramuros','PRO-MAN extramuros','PRO-MAN intramuros'  )
  AND    PROJECT.PNAME  IN  ( 'eNotices', 'TED Applications', 'TED Web Services', 'TED-Monitor-2012',  'eTendering'  )
  AND  ( CUSTOMFIELDVALUE.STRINGVALUE=TO_CHAR(CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.ID) AND CUSTOMFIELDOPTION.CUSTOMVALUE='Performed' )
  AND    JIRAISSUE.RESOLUTION=8
ORDER by issuenum;
```